# How to modify the authortitle citation style?

Tags: biblatex

I require directions on how to modify the `authortitle` citation style as follows. Take this entry, for example:

```
@incollection{ruediger2014,
    author = {Rüdiger, Jan AND Foerster, Thomas},
    title = {Aemulatio -- Recusatio. Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden},
    booktitle = {Akkulturation im Mittelalter},
    editor = {Härtel, Reinhard},
    year = {2014},
    series = {Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte. Vorträge und Forschungen},
    number = {78},
    address = {Ostfildern},
    pages = {441-497},
    shorttitle = {Aemulatio -- Recusatio}
```

It will produce this (German) output:

> Rüdiger, Jan und Thomas Foerster: "Aemulatio -- Recusatio. Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden". In: Akkulturation im Mittelalter. Hrsg. von Reinhard Härtel. Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte. Vorträge und Forschungen 78. Ostfildern 2014, S. 441-497.

What my supervisor needs me to do is to have the series right before the pages, like so:

> Rüdiger, Jan und Thomas Foerster: "Aemulatio -- Recusatio. Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden". In: Akkulturation im Mittelalter. Hrsg. von Reinhard Härtel. Ostfildern 2014 (= Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte. Vorträge und Forschungen 78), S. 441-497.

The same would have to apply for `@book` type entries, where the series should appear at the very end (again, in parentheses).

If you could put me on track here, you'd make me very happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblatex-dw` styles have an option and an customisable punctuation command for these sort of things.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-dw, series=afteryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\seriespunct}{=\addspace}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{ruediger2014,
  author    = {Rüdiger, Jan and Foerster, Thomas},
  title     = {Aemulatio -- Recusatio},
  subtitle  = {Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden},
  booktitle = {Akkulturation im Mittelalter},
  editor    = {Härtel, Reinhard},
  year      = {2014},
  series    = {Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte.
               Vorträge und Forschungen},
  number    = {78},
  address   = {Ostfildern},
  pages     = {441-497},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ruediger2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Rüdiger, Jan und Thomas Foerster: Aemulatio – Recusatio. Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden, in: Reinhard Härtel (Hrsg.): Akkulturation im Mittelalter, Ostfildern 2014 (= Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte. Vorträge und Forschungen 78), S. 441–497.]

---

If you do not want to buy into all the changes switching to `authortitle-dw` would entail, you can use the `biblatex-ext` style `ext-authortitle` that is a drop-in replacement for the standard `authortitle` style with a few additional customisation features.

You would then modify the `series+number` macro and add a renamed version later after printing the publisher and location info. (Most of that could easily be done in standard `biblatex` as well, but `biblatex-ext` makes it easier to redefine all `publisher`/`organization`/`institution`+`location`+`date` macros at once.)

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authortitle]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{}

\newbibmacro*{series+number:paren}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext{=}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number:paren}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{ruediger2014,
  author    = {Rüdiger, Jan and Foerster, Thomas},
  title     = {Aemulatio -- Recusatio},
  subtitle  = {Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden},
  booktitle = {Akkulturation im Mittelalter},
  editor    = {Härtel, Reinhard},
  year      = {2014},
  series    = {Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte.
               Vorträge und Forschungen},
  number    = {78},
  address   = {Ostfildern},
  pages     = {441-497},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ruediger2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Rüdiger, Jan und Thomas Foerster. „Aemulatio – Recusatio. Strategien der Akkulturation im europäischen Norden“. In: Akkulturation im Mittelalter. Hrsg. von Reinhard Härtel. Ostfildern, 2014 (= Konstanzer Arbeitskreis für mittelalterliche Geschichte. Vorträge und Forschungen 78), S. 441–497.]

Comment: A perfect answer, thank you so very much!